# Open Source WinForm Controls

Tags: c#, winforms

Is anyone aware of open source WinForm controls similar to what Infragistics or Telerik might offer? I'm looking for the standard controls like edit controls, grid etc. But I also want a tab like control and a slideout control would be nice too.

Thanks

Comment: These kind of controls are only worth what you paid for them.

Comment: Metroframework is half decent for free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are out there if you do some digging, albeit spread out and inconsistent. I used a file tree that I found on Code Project once although like Hans says, the free option is not always a good idea if you need a good quality control - we ended up using Syncfusion.

Answer (score 1):

Have you searched through any sites hosting open source projects, like [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net) or [GitHub](http://github.com)?

Comment: I'm hoping for some recommendations from people who have used open source tools.

Answer (score 1):

I have a set of open source WinForm controls that offer quite a few features, but my toolkit does not yet have editor controls.  I may include editor controls in the future.  However, if you want some graphically and feature rich controls, my open source DotCoolControls library I wrote includes many of these.  The controls currently included in the DotCoolControls library include a button, checkbox, radio button, label, panel and a base control, from which all DotCoolControls are derived and which you can inherit and use to design your own controls.  All these controls are made from scratch (except the panel) and offer advanced GDI+ features, such as custom shapes, gradients and user effects.

In addition, I have also made an extension of the stock .Net DataGridView control which is called the DotCoolGridView control.  This control has all the same features of the DataGridView with the addition of several graphical features, such as gradient and image backgrounds, gradient column headers and utilizes alpha-blending and row and cell selectors.

You can download the DotCoolControls and DotCoolGridView controls on my Github page.

These controls are still a work in progress and I plan on adding several other open source WinForms controls and components in the future.  In addition, I will try to merge my Tiferix.Json library with the DotCoolGridView in the future so you can at design time bind the grid to a Tiferix.JsonDataSchema file.

All controls are licensed under LGPL and can be used in both commercial and open source software free of charge.

Here are the links on my Github page:
[DotCoolControls library](https://github.com/jontiefer/DotCoolControls)

[DotCoolGridView library](https://github.com/jontiefer/DotCoolGridView)

Answer (score 0):

Search for Winforms at codeplex. Archives are still available for download. I found about 30 projects with customs Winforms controls and innovations: xaml for Winforms!, reskinnable Winforms!

I'm implying you should write your own controls, so these give you examples.  The problem with commercial controls is: 1) they are closed source so not easy to fix if broke, nor change. 2) they always have more features than you use. You pay for someone else's features. 3) they are never exactly what you need.